# how to update global variable in titanium?

Tags: arrays, global-variables, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

i'm having some problem in updating my array which is global by the way.

here is my code:

```
Ti.App.dinercolor=["#FF5A00","#007EFF","#dccdc0","#C2FF95","#A700FD","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#5F9EA0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#22A000","#DCCDC0","#dccdc0","#FF003C","#dccdc0","#FF003C","#dccdc0","#22A000","#dccdc0","#FFF191"];
```

thats my global array which i can access data from it from anywhere in the application.

the problem comes when i want to update the array like:

```
for(var q=0; q<Ti.App.dinercolor.length; q++){Ti.App.dinercolor[q] = '#dccdc0';}
```

so, the array i was expecting after the operation thats done is something like this:

```
Ti.App.dinercolor=["#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0"];
```

but somehow i'm getting the same array with out updating,

```
Ti.App.dinercolor=["#FF5A00","#007EFF","#dccdc0","#C2FF95","#A700FD","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#5F9EA0","#dccdc0","#dccdc0","#22A000","#DCCDC0","#dccdc0","#FF003C","#dccdc0","#FF003C","#dccdc0","#22A000","#dccdc0","#FFF191"];
```

please help me out, i have no idea what i'm doing wrong here,

Thank you,,

Comment: are all operations performed within the same file? give a short overview about your file structure (e.g. Ti.includes etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you shouldn't extend the Ti object as unexpected things like this will happen. Create your own object and it will work.

```
myObj = {};
myObj.dinercolor = [];
```

And so on.

It is recommended you keep your app in a single context so you will be able to access the object from anywhere. Check out [the forging titanium](http://vimeopro.com/appcelerator/forging-titanium) video series for some best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jeff, however if you want the above approach to work you will need to update the whole array, you cannot just update elements.

So read the array out into a new variable, update the specific elements and then set the property again

Answer (score 0):

In App.js:

```
Ti.App.my_variable = 0;
```

In some_other_page.js:

```
Ti.App.my_variable = 101;
```

In yet_another_page.js:

```
alert( Ti.App.my_variable );
```

This will alert 101 !!