# Sharing global variables between two js files

Tags: javascript, titanium, global-variables

I'm working with two js files and sharing variables between them in a titanium app. In my main app.js I have 3 variables associated with each row in a table. I have an event listener for when a row is clicked to open a modal view whose components are in a separate js file. My three variables are below and on the click event I have an alert of the 3 variables and the 3 global variables.

```
var titleText = titleInRow.text;
var artistText=artistInRow.text;

Ti.App.myGlobalSongVar = titleText;
Ti.App.myGlobalArtistVar = artistText;

var rowNumber=e.row.name;
Ti.App.myGlobalRowNumber= rowNumber;

alert("titleText is: "+titleText+" and /n artistText is "+artistText+ " and /n row number is "+rowNumber +"/n TiAppmyGlobalSongVar is "+Ti.App.myGlobalSongVar+ " /n TiAppmyGlobalArtistVar is "+Ti.App.myGlobalArtistVar);
```

These are all returning the correct results. Then in my second js file, I also have the following alert:

```
alert("\n TiAppmyGlobalSongVar in modal is "+Ti.App.myGlobalSongVar+ " \n TiAppmyGlobalArtistVar in modal is "+Ti.App.myGlobalArtistVar + "TiAppmyGlobalRowNumber in modal is "+Ti.App.myGlobalRowNumber);
```

In the second js file The first time I click on a row, my second alert's variables are all undefined. The second time I click they are all defined but sometimes wrong. It seems to give the results of the variables for the row I first clicked which was undefined. Hope this question was clear. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE PLEASE READ!!:**
In the end, after trying:

```
Titanium.API.titleText = titleText;
Titanium.API.artistText = artistText;
```

and

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('globalTitleText', titleText);
Ti.App.Properties.setString('globalArtistText', artistText);
```

and

```
Ti.App.myGlobalSongVar = titleText;
Ti.App.myGlobalArtistVar = artistText;
```

(which ALL worked the second time, but were undefined the first),
the only thing which worked was firing this event in my table event listener:

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('myCustomEvent', {
          myTitleText: titleText,
          myArtistText: artistText
        });
```

and having this in my second js file:

```
var globalTitleText;
var globalArtistText;
    Ti.App.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', function(event) {
            globalTitleText=event.myTitleText;
            globalTitleText=event.myTitleText;
            //Ti.App.globalTitleText=event.myTitleText;
            //Ti.App.globalArtistText=event.myArtistText;
            alert('You sent me: '+event.myTitleText+" and "+event.myArtistText);
    });

//However I can't use it here in my second js file (outside the custom event listener) as it is undefined.
```

Can anyone help me with the last bit of the problem? 
I still don't know why the other methods didn't work. I've used them in different contexts before and they did work, but not in this particular instance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following code IN the eventListener?

> ```
> var titleText = titleInRow.text;
> var artistText=artistInRow.text;
>
> Ti.App.myGlobalSongVar = titleText;
> Ti.App.myGlobalArtistVar = artistText;
>
> var rowNumber=e.row.name;
> Ti.App.myGlobalRowNumber= rowNumber;
> ```

Because for your variables to be global, you need to declare them outside the eventListener function. Something like:

```
var rowNumber;
tableView.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    rowNumber = e.rowIndex;
}
```

`rowNumber` will be global if declared in App.js, whereas:

```
tableView.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    var rowNumber;
    rowNumber = e.rowIndex;
}
```

won't.

Comment: thanks. This led me to the solution, the only way I got it working was by:                                                       var titleText;                                                        var artistText;                                                                  var rowNumber; tableView.addEventListener("click", function (e){ titleText = titleInRow.text;
artistText=artistInRow.text;
  
Ti.App.myGlobalSongVar = titleText;
Ti.App.myGlobalArtistVar = artistText;

Comment: var rowNumber=e.row.name;
Ti.App.myGlobalRowNumber= rowNumber;
}); I could then access Ti.App.MyglobalArtistVar, Ti.App.MyglobalSongVar etc. in the second js :)

Answer (score 0):

Pleasee go through this link in titanium developer forum

[Global Variables in Titanium](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/138892/how-i-define-global-variable-in-titanium)

.........................

And it's also best to pass your own object it works in that case.

[Passing object as global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552752/how-to-update-global-variable-in-titanium)

Please Check it out and let me know

**Note :** also declare the variables in App.js :) if any value is to be modifies then do it in other JS.

Comment: @ Iopa I tried the method in your first link which was Titanium.API.titleText=titleText; etc. but that did the same thing. It was undefined the first time I clicked a row and the second time it was defined but seemed to give the variable value for the row clicked first

Comment: Try creating an object like

Comment: Titanium.API.titleText = {name : titleText}

and try define them in App.js

Comment: @Iopa thanks for the response. I also tried the get and set string method with Ti.App.properties. Got the exact same results. It's only two strings I need to share. How would I create an object?

Comment: @Iopa and then how would I reference it from the second js?

Comment: Go through this link

it has Ti.App.properties.SetString and getstring

even setObject and getObject 

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties


objects are easy to create ... any thing written in -> {} can be an object

Comment: @Iopa At the minute, I have:                                                 var titleText = titleInRow.text;                                     var artistText=artistInRow.text;
Titanium.API.titleText = {name : titleText};
Titanium.API.artistText = {name : artistText}; and then in my second js file I tried to access the variables like: Titanium.API.titleText.name but that returns an error that it cannot read property name of undefined, in my second js

Comment: @Iopa thanks for the link, As I said earlier however, I tried the get and set string methods with Ti.App.properties and had the same issue as I started with